# Place UICollectionViewCell at a certain postion iOS

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have two prototype cells in my CollectionView. Also, I have a list of 6 items that I pass to these cells. Depending on their index I assign the prototypes like so :-

```
if (indexPath.Row == 0 || indexPath.Row ==2 || indexPath.Row ==3)
            {
                smallCell = (DefaultCollectionCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("Default_Cell", indexPath);
                smallCell.PopulateData(tag);

                return smallCell;

            }
            else 
            {
                cell = (NewCollectionCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("New_Collection_Cell", indexPath);
                cell.PopulateData(tag);
                return cell;
            }
```

adjust their heights and widths. Like so :-

```
 switch(indexPath.Row)
            {
                case 0:
                    cellWidth = bounds.Width / 4;
                    cellHeight = bounds.Height / 4;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cellWidth = bounds.Width / 2;
                    cellHeight = bounds.Height / 4;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cellWidth = bounds.Width / 4;
                    cellHeight = bounds.Height / 4;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cellWidth = bounds.Width / 2;
                    cellHeight = bounds.Height/ 0.75f;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    cellWidth = bounds.Width / 2;
                    cellHeight = bounds.Height / 4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    cellWidth = bounds.Width / 2;
                    cellHeight = bounds.Height / 4;
                    break;
             }
```

I want an output like so :- 
[image]

But my output currently is:-
[image]

I get the first 3 items placed properly, but the last 3 items look weird as I want the 6rh item under 4th and not under 5th. Is there a way I can adjust this?

Answer (score 0):

The cells are re-cycled, so you can't count on it's position, remember they are constructed on the fly as they become visible, so position 1 isn't always position 1

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I there a way I can achieve the layout Iam looking for then?